# Seed data .net core

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to seed the DB in .net core with data.
Firstly I seed users , userrole, roles with an admin user correctly.
Due to requirements of the project I made two models Instructor,Student
I seed with another script these tables too.
I want for every instructor and student to see Users table (Iwant seperate tables for authorization)
I write the following script runs last in program.cs file

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using WebApplication.Models;

 namespace WebApplication.Data
 {
    public static class AssingUsers
    {
    public static void Initialize(IConfiguration Configuration, ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManage)
    {
        AddUser(Configuration, context, UserManage);
        AddUserRoles(Configuration, context, UserManage);
    }

    private static async void AddUser(IConfiguration Configuration, ApplicationDbContext DBContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager)
    {
        if (DBContext.Instructors.Any())
        {
            foreach (Instructor instructor in DBContext.Instructors)
            {
                var User = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = instructor.Email,
                    Email = instructor.Email,
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };
                await UserManager.CreateAsync(User, Configuration["Password"]);
            }
        }

        if (DBContext.Students.Any())
        {
            foreach (Student student in DBContext.Students)
            {
                var User = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = student.Email,
                    Email = student.Email,
                    EmailConfirmed = true
                };
                await UserManager.CreateAsync(User, Configuration["Password"]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void AddUserRoles(IConfiguration Configuration, ApplicationDbContext DBContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager)
    {
        if (DBContext.Students.Any())
        {
            foreach (Student st in DBContext.Students)
            {
                var UserRole = new IdentityUserRole<string>
                {
                    UserId = DBContext.Users.Single(r => r.Email == st.Email).Id,
                    RoleId = DBContext.Roles.Single(r => r.Name == "User").Id
                };
                DBContext.UserRoles.Add(UserRole);
            }
            DBContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (DBContext.Instructors.Any())
        {
            foreach (Instructor ins in DBContext.Instructors)
            {
                var UserRole = new IdentityUserRole<string>
                {
                    UserId = DBContext.Users.Single(x => x.Email == ins.Email).Id,
                    RoleId = DBContext.Roles.Single(x => x.Name == "Manager").Id
                };
                DBContext.UserRoles.Add(UserRole);
            }
            DBContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
   }
```

Although everything runs perfect, I have problem while seeding the instructors and students table.
I tried sync via _context.Users.Add() but again nothing.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using Entity framework code first approach?

Comment: Yes I am using this approach

Comment: DB is synchrozed perfectly with migrations

Comment: You can override the Up and Down method and use it for seeding.

Comment: I do not want to do it with static way.

Comment: Just create 5 Instructros and students and start seeding. Simple way, clear wa. Althouh I will try from migration to update

Comment: Or, you can inherit the DropCreateDatabaseAlways<T> class pass in your context as generic parameter T, and in the base constructor write this: Database.SetInitializer<T>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<T>()); where T is your context